# What does 富 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

"売春を行う女性は、古くから存在する職業とされる。職業とは、ヒトのみが行う社会的かつ文化的営為であり`、富、`付加価値の交換により形作られる経済活動の手段としては、売春がやはり人類最古の職業の一つである。"

I know that the meaning of 富 is wealth but it doesn't suit the context well, and I have the impression that this word could just be removed and it would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

富 is a vague term that broadly refers to things that are considered to have financial values. Money, real estate, precious metals, jewelry, food, oil, pepper, and so on.

In the modern society 富 mainly refers to money itself, but in the old days it could have been stones, seashells or [bags of rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koku) which people sought in order to be "rich". I don't know what the first prostitutes in the human history gained in return :)

Comment: I see, but I don't understand the link this word has with the text because it is between 2 commas in the middle of the text...?

Comment: Oh, those two commas are different. The comma before 富 is a normal comma to indicate a break, whereas `富、付加価値の交換` just means `富と付加価値の交換` (exchanging 富 and 付加価値).

Comment: <<economic activities formed of the exchange of wealth and "added value">>
 it seems a little weird, Am I wrong ?

Comment: @jirei "as a means of economic activities formed by exchanging property and [values added](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added)"